# How to set the reference to the current user, in CloudKit?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I have a `CKRecordType` with a reference field that I want to set to the current user of the app.
[image]

```
CKRecord * record = [[CKRecord alloc] initWithRecordType:@"UserStatus"];
[record setValue:@"online" forKey:@"status"];
// what user should be?
[record setValue:user forKey:@"user"];
```

How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the `userId`:

```
- (void)getUserId
{
    [self.defaultContainer fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler:^(CKRecordID * _Nullable recordID,
                                                                    NSError * _Nullable error)
     {
         if (error == nil)
         {
             self.userRecordID = recordID;
         }
     }];
}
```

Then:

```
CKRecord * record = [[CKRecord alloc] initWithRecordType:@"UserStatus"];
record[@"status"] = @"online";

CKReference *userReference = [[CKReference alloc] initWithRecordID:self.userRecordID action:CKReferenceActionDeleteSelf];
record[@"user"] = userReference;
```